# Cannot add foreign key constraint error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

In the given Images, There are two tables. In the table STUD_MEMBER, Dept_ID is a foreign key which is referring to Dept_ID in table DEPARTMENT.:

[image: Image of Tables]

So when I add foreign key constraints in mysql at phpmyadmin like

```
 CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(
 Dept_ID INT, 
 Dept_Name VARCHAR(25));



INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES(1,"Information Technology");
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES(2,"Electrical");
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES(3,"Civil");
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES(4,"Mechanical");
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES(5,"Chemical");



 CREATE TABLE STUD_MEMBER(
 Roll_No INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 FName VARCHAR(20),
 MName VARCHAR(20),
 SName VARCHAR(20), 
 Dept_ID INT,
 FOREIGN KEY (Dept_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(Dept_ID),
 Semester INT,
 Contact_No INT,
 Gender VARCHAR(6));
```

It is showing an error that 1215- cannot add foreign key constraint. As far as I know, it is the correct way to add a foreign key, I am so confused why it is wrong. Please help in solving this.

Comment: Please Click on the link of the Image, As I am first time using stackoverflow, I don't know why it is not appearing here?

Comment: `Dept_ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` <-- use this, but based on the documentation you should not be getting this error in the first place.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thank you so much. I was doing this mistake. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the referenced column has to be either a primary key, or it has to have a unique index.  The following `CREATE TABLE` statement worked for me:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
    Dept_ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Dept_Name VARCHAR(25)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are defining foreign key in child, the parent field must have an index defined on it.

check reference from [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT
```